# How do I choose a replacement Derailleur?

Tags: derailleur

I have a Psycle Werks downhill-bike and the derailleur got bent and cracked I need it to get replaced does anyone know or have any suggestions on where I can get a new one or what I should do?

Comment: Your local bike shop? It’s not an easy repair especially if you bent your derailleur hanger or dropout.

Comment: Well, either take the bike to a good local bike shop - or - figure out what type of derailleur you need, order one from an online bike store and install it yourself. If you don't know much about bike mechanics I highly recommend the first option. If you want to at least figure out what the type of derailleur you have, edit your post to add the number of gears in the rear, and add some photos of the derailleur.

Comment: Thanks for the help I don’t know how many gears it has but i took it to a shop that i thought was good and they told me they cant fix it cause the derailleur i have on it now isn’t made anymore

Comment: Well, aren't there other derailleurs compatible with your drivetrain? Unless your bicycle is from 1800's I doubt there are no replacement parts available. As for gears number, if you can count to ten you can find this number out by looking at your cassette.

Comment: You need a better bike shop. Don’t go to the bike department of your supermarket, go to a real bike shop.

Comment: @DetriDunn if you can't figure out how many gears you have, take two clear and well-lit photos, and edit them into your question.  One of the cassette from the back, and one of the derailleur from the right-hand side of the bike.

Comment: Older derailleurs in reasonable working condition can also be found on Ebay if you really need a particular model.

Comment: I'm not sure if recommending a replacement part to someone who doesn't know how many gears they have is a good idea.... At minimum, to replace the derailleur, they'll need a chain breaker, a set of allens, and torque wrench -- if not cable cutters/crimpers and a derailleur hanger tool. They'll also need the capability to adjust the derailleur. It's not a beginner repair. Not impossible, but I wouldn't give it to someone who doesn't know how many gears they have.

Comment: At the least we can inform the OP about what derailleurs would be compatible, so they are armed with some knowledge when dealing with repair shops. Or perhaps they can source an appropriate derailleur themselves and have a repair shop install it.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, Argenti. Thanks for clarifying your rationale, I agree. I do think that most shops will want to install their own derailleur and not one bought off the internet -- partly because of the additional profit but also because there's a possibility it won't fit or that the new part is broken and it's much easier to deal with the shop's own vendor than it is to tell the customer that they got the wrong part or the part they got is broken.  So many shops will charge additional labor for outside-bought parts or subsidize their own labor costs when they install their own parts.

Comment: You certainly don't need a torque wrench to install a derailleur, and technically you can get away without chain breaker if you take apart the cage for installation. I wouldn't recommend the latter to someone who doesn't know how many speeds their bike has :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your new derailleur is dependent on the number of gears you have on the back and sometimes brand dependent. SRAM and Shimano, have (they used to have at least) different pull ratios and/or inverted numbers (which is not a problem, only a funny fact), so this are the first thing to check out.

Then as you said you do DH, so you need in my opinion a short, or medium length derailleur; so it doesn't bounce that much and also to have a little more clearance for obstacles.

That said there are some derailleurs that have clutch systems so the cage won't move as you hit bumps and obstacles, for a more consistent pedaling.

If you have the money go for a Shimano Saint, Hone or SLX. Then again if you don't have it, go for a Shimano XT 98. If you have a small ratio transmission in the back (tooth count doesn't differ that much from gear to gear) you can get a away with a derailleur made for road bike, small and light.

PS: You can get your old derailleur straight with the use of two french-wrenches (crescent wrench), one to set the direction to bend and the other to apply force to the first one.

Cheers.